# Understanding Kleisli vis-a-vis `bind`

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to understand what Kleisli, i.e. `>=>`, provides over `bind` (`>>=`).

Looking at their signatures of `bind` and `Klesli`, respectively:

```
λ: :t (>>=)
(>>=) :: Monad m => m a -> (a -> m b) -> m b

λ: :t (>=>)
(>=>) :: Monad m => (a -> m b) -> (b -> m c) -> a -> m c
```

And then this example:

```
λ: let plus10 = \x -> return (x + 10)
λ: let minus5 = \x -> return (x - 5)
```

I can use either function call:

```
λ: return 5 >>= plus10 >>= minus5
10

λ: (>=>) plus10 minus5 5
10
```

Of course this is a single, simple example. However, what is the importance of `Kleisli` over `bind`? From looking at their function definitions, I wonder if every `Kleisli` function usage can be re-written using `bind`.

Comment: [`>=>`  is implemented in terms of `>>=`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.1.0/docs/src/Control.Monad.html#%3E%3D%3E) so there is nothing more than convenience

Comment: One reason you might like `>=>` over `>>=` is how beautiful the monad laws are: `(f >=> g) >=> h = f >=> (g >=> h)` and `return >=> f = f >=> return = f`. Compare with the laws written in terms of `>>=` and you will see a stark difference.

Answer (score 3):

It's similar more or less to the difference between `(.)` and `($)` (or function application).

For example, if I wanted to count the number of even numbers in a list, I could do:

```
countEven = length . filter even
```

Or I could do

```
countEven xs = length $ filter even $ xs
```

Which really are the same thing, and compile/inline to the same thing in the end, but the two "mean" different things.

The first one says, "`countEven` is the length of an even-filtered list".  The second one says, "to get the number of evens in this list, filter it with `filter even`, and then apply `length` to the result".

Different ways of saying the same thing.  And you could definitely implement one each in terms of the other:

```
f . g = \x -> f $ g $ x
```

Comment: the parallel is clearer seen with `x |> f = f x`: the associativity law of Monad `(m >>= a) >>= b === m >>= (a >=> b)` becomes `(x |> f) |> g === x |> (f >>> g)` where of course `f >>> g === g . f`. IOW `b =<< (a =<< m) === (b <=< a) =<< m` becomes `g $ (f $ x) === (g . f) x`, just as you wrote. Indeed, Kleisli composition forms a category, as [the haiku](https://wiki.haskell.org/Monad_laws) says.

Answer (score 0):

As Justin said it's like `.`. You can rewrite your example as `(>=>) plus10 minus5 5` as `return 5 >>= (plus10 >=> plus5)`, you can compare easily the two version

```
λ: return 5 >>= plus10 >>= minus5
10
λ: return 5 >>= (plus10 >=> minus5)
10
```

In other word, if you want to write a a point-free version, you can't just write `plus10 >>= minus5`, you need to use `>=>` instead.